# Laravel 5: Request::file всегда null

Tags: laravel, php, request, файлы, form

Пытаюсь залить изображение через форму.

Форма:

```
     <form action="/newimages" method="post" >
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token()
 }}">
          <label>Прикрепить изображение</label>
          <input name="img" type="file">
          <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
     </form>
```

Контроллер:

```
 public function addImg(){
         $input = Request::all();
         $file = Request::file('img');
         var_dump($input);
         var_dump($file);
     }
```

Вывод после обработки:

```
array(4) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "kukFaGwEZSMpPRqUS0gjWVJy4caEJBK3PgldA2Ue" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["body"]=> string(0) "" ["image"]=> string(14) "image_name.jpg" } 
NULL
```

Картинка вроде прикрепляется, но `Request::file('img')` всегда отдает NULL. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @pavlike, похоже, вы забыли прописать enctype="multipart/formdata" самой форме, поэтому вместо самих файлов уходят только названия.

Comment: @Etki, увы, все так же null :( 
p.s. только все же form-data вроде

Comment: @pavlike, да, конечно через дефис. Посмотрите, что валяется в $_FILES - может он почему-то все-таки не доходит.

Comment: @Etki, array(0) там. Я даже не знаю в какую сторону копать.

Comment: @pavlike и при этом имя файла так же приходит строкой?

Comment: @Etki, да. Причуды laravel? По оф. документации же делаю.

Comment: @pavlike, нет, скорее всего форма неправильно отправляется. enctype точно правильно прописывали? когда файлы уходят, во вкладке network консоли хрома присутствует слово boundary? (если не хватает комментариев, старые можно удалять)

Comment: @Etki, не поленился, поставил чистую лару, на ней все заработало. Видимо, где-то ранее я накосячил, буду смотреть. Спасибо за поддержку.

Comment: @pavlike, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Форма:

```
<form action="/post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Метод контроллера:

```
public function addImg(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $file = $request->file('img');
    var_dump($input);
    var_dump($file);
}
```

или

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// ...
public function addImg(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $file = $request->file('img');
    var_dump($input);
    var_dump($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к атрибутам формы свойство:

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```